# How to append data from one CSV column to another in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have the following CSV file output:

```
Customer,Misc
customer1,business-dns-test2
customer2,dns-test2
customer1,dns-test1
```

The goal at hand is to append `customer1` the string `-business` only if the word is present in the same row under `Misc`.

That is, I am looking for the final CSV output to be:

```
Customer,Misc
customer1-business,dns-test2
customer2,dns-test2
customer1,dns-test1
```

Essentially, the keyword here is `business`. I need to make sure `customer1` and `customer1-business` are treated as separate customers despite them sharing the same name `customer1`.

Thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems like a job for the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module of the standard library with some simple dictionary and string manipulation.

Comment: Are you also deleting `business` from the second field? This is what you have in your example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
df.loc[df.Misc.str.startswith('business'),'Customer']+='-business'
df.Misc=df.Misc.str.strip('business-')
df
Out[93]: 
             Customer       Misc
0  customer1-business  dns-test2
1           customer2  dns-test2
2           customer1  dns-test1
```